# Mysql Employee break time history with time difference

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I have employee biometric log data with `inoutmode` flag. I am trying to get detail break time list and with time difference.

`inoutmode` 4 as break-out and 5 as break-in.

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (105, '2019-09-19', '14:00:13', 4);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (105, '2019-09-19', '16:07:08', 4);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (105, '2019-09-19', '16:07:18', 5);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (235, '2019-09-19', '15:44:26', 4);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (235, '2019-09-19', '16:37:58', 4);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (235, '2019-09-19', '20:01:11', 5);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (235, '2019-09-19', '20:01:25', 5);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (235, '2019-09-19', '20:30:29', 4);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (326, '2019-09-19', '15:58:30', 4);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (326, '2019-09-19', '19:34:09', 5);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (327, '2019-09-19', '15:44:19', 5);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (327, '2019-09-19', '15:55:37', 4);
INSERT INTO `tbl_downloadentry` (`EmpMachineID`, `shift_date`, `AttenTime`, `InOutMode`) VALUES (327, '2019-09-19', '19:59:38', 4);
```

here's my **Desired Output**

```
| EmpMachineID | attendance_date | break_out  | break_in  | Diff      |
|--------------|-----------------|------------|-----------|-----------|
| 235          | 2019-09-19      | 15:44:26   |           |           |
|              | 2019-09-19      | 16:37:58   |           |           |
|              | 2019-09-19      |            | 20:01:11  |           |
|              | 2019-09-19      | 20:30:29   | 20:01:25  |    29:04  |
| 326          | 2019-09-19      | 19:34:09   | 15:58:30  | 03:35:39  |
```

I tried my best to achieve the output. Following is my attempted query:

```
SELECT l2.empmachineid,
       l2.shift_date,
       l2.attentime,
       l2.inoutmode
FROM   tbl_downloadentry AS l2
WHERE  l2.inoutmode IN ( 5, 4 )
       AND l2.shift_date = "2019-09-19"
ORDER  BY l2.empmachineid,
          l2.shift_date,
          l2.attentime ASC
```

My MySQL version = **10.3.17-MariaDB-1-log**

```
SELECT l2.EmpMachineID, l2.shift_date, l2.InOutMode, 
       case when l2.InOutMode=5 then l2.AttenTime END AS BreakOut, 
       case when l2.InOutMode=4 then l2.AttenTime END AS BreakIn
FROM tbl_downloadentry AS l2
WHERE l2.InOutMode IN (5, 4) AND l2.shift_date="2019-09-19"
ORDER BY l2.EmpMachineID, l2.shift_date, l2.AttenTime ASC
```

partially i arrived the records using case condition but 4 and 5 inoutmode should be in single line to calculate the time difference. Any idea...

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Did you attempt any query ? Please edit the question and add your attempt as well,so that we can push you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your responce @Madhur. i am trying my best to achive the output. below i mentioned the query.<br /><br />```SELECT l2.EmpMachineID, l2.shift_date, l2.AttenTime, l2.InOutMode
FROM tbl_downloadentry AS l2
WHERE l2.InOutMode IN (5,4) AND l2.shift_date="2019-09-19"
ORDER BY l2.EmpMachineID, l2.shift_date, l2.AttenTime ASC;````

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58037389/edit) the question and add the query there, in proper formatting. Don't use comments for such things. Also, what is your MySQL server version ? Run `SELECT Version();` on your mysql client, and please update the question with version details also.

Comment: Sorry i did same what you said. i don't know how to use.

Comment: In your desired output, why don't you have rows for `EmpMachineID = 105 and 327` ?

Comment: Just i update the sample output. once query is ok it will apply to all the EmpMachineID.

Comment: ok thanks. Will you able to help me on this condition?

Comment: Your Desired Output is inconsistent with your data - '15:44:26' is given mode 4 (break-out) in your insert data, it is shown as break-in in your desired output column. Have you swapped the columns in the desired output by mistake?

Comment: Sorry i mistakenly placed incorrect record. kinly swap it in query in will edit the desired output

Comment: Your example output is still inconsistent with the data - for machine 326, your data lists '15:58:30' as a break-out time, the desired output shows this as an input time. (I'm trying to test a query that should do this, but it is not matching your desired output, apparently because of these data errors)

Comment: @PeterBarton - Please swap the data. actually '15:58:30' is Break-Out time and '19:34:09' is Break-In Time. little bit confuse in InOutMode flag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an approach utilizing [`LEAD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lead) and [`LAG()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) Window functions available in MariaDB 10.2+ and MySQL 8+.

- When a particular's row `InOutMode` mode is `4`, that means it is a `break_out` time. Now, we use `LAG()` function to get the immediate **previous** row for that particular EmpID. Ordering is defined based on the Time. So if the immediate previous row's `InOutMode` mode is `5`, that implies that we have a corresponding `break_in` time for this `break_out` time, else `null`.
- Similar process is followed for the row with `InOutMode` mode being `5`. Only difference this time is that we use `LEAD()` function instead; because we need to get the immediate **next** row, and check if it is `break_out` or not.
- Now, we simply need to use this result-set as a [Derived Table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-tables.html) and `DISTINCT` it out (because we will have duplicate rows for every case where there are break_in and break_out together). Also, in the outer query we can calculate the time difference using [`TimeDiff()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) functionality.

Following query is done for `EmpID = 235` for demo purpose:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT 
    dt.*, 
    TIMEDIFF(dt.break_out, dt.break_in) AS diff 
FROM 
(
SELECT  
  EmpMachineID, 
  shift_date, 
  CASE InOutMode 
    WHEN 4 THEN AttenTime -- this is break_out row
    WHEN 5 THEN -- this is break_in row, find the break_out if exists
      CASE 
        WHEN LEAD(InOutMode) OVER w = 4 
        THEN LEAD(AttenTime) OVER w 
      END       
  END AS break_out, 
  CASE InOutMode 
    WHEN 5 THEN AttenTime -- this is break_in row
    WHEN 4 THEN   -- this is break_out row, find the break_in if exists
      CASE 
        WHEN LAG(InOutMode) OVER w = 5 
        THEN LAG(AttenTime) OVER w 
      END  
  END AS break_in
FROM tbl_downloadentry 
WHERE EmpMachineID = 235 
AND InOutMode IN (4,5) 
AND shift_date = '2019-09-19' 
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY EmpMachineID
             ORDER BY AttenTime ASC)
) AS dt;
```

**Result**

```
| EmpMachineID | shift_date | break_out | break_in | diff     |
| ------------ | ---------- | --------- | -------- | -------- |
| 235          | 2019-09-19 | 15:44:26  |          |          |
| 235          | 2019-09-19 | 16:37:58  |          |          |
| 235          | 2019-09-19 |           | 20:01:11 |          |
| 235          | 2019-09-19 | 20:30:29  | 20:01:25 | 00:29:04 |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/tP5BiyupHpEwURAY8K7hh5/0)

Comment: @YathavSriTechnology welcome :) I have added explanation to the answer just now; go through it for proper understanding

Comment: any possibility to run this LEAD() and LAG() Window functions available in MariaDB 10.1+

Comment: @YathavSriTechnology No. [Windows functions are introduced in MariaDB 10.2.0 onwards only](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/window-functions/)

Comment: This query was successfully working in my development pc but not working in client pc. MariaDB 10.1.13 any other way to change the query based on 10.1.13?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to associate "4" records with "5" records.  Your result set seems to have little to do with your sample data, so it is hard to follow.

The following approach associates each 4/5 with the nearest one.  It does this by assigning a grouping, counting up for each "4" and down for each "5".

However, this is not quite the whole solution, because there can be multiple ups and downs as series of "4"s and "5" are in a row.  So, it assigns a secondary grouping, to break up this up.

```
SELECT EmpMachineID, shift_date,
       MAX(CASE WHEN InOutMode = 4 THEN AttenTime END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN InOutMode = 5 THEN AttenTime END)
FROM (SELECT dl.*,
             SUM(InOutMode = group_first_InOutMode) OVER (PARTITION BY dl.EmpMachineID, dl.shift_date, dl.grouping ORDER BY dl.AttenTime) as secondary_grouping
      FROM (SELECT dl.*,
                   FIRST_VALUE(InOutMode) OVER (PARTITION BY dl.EmpMachineID, dl.shift_date, dl.grouping ORDER BY dl.AttenTime) as group_first_InOutMode
            FROM (SELECT dl.*,
                         SUM( CASE WHEN InOutMode = 4 THEN 1 WHEN InOutMode = 5 THEN -1 END) OVER
                              (PARTITION BY dl.EmpMachineID, dl.shift_date
                               ORDER BY dl.AttenTime
                              ) -
                              (CASE WHEN InOutMode = 5 THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) as grouping  -- subtract out "5"s on current row
                 FROM tbl_downloadentry dl
                 WHERE dl.InOutMode IN (5, 4) AND dl.shift_date = '2019-09-19'
                ) dl
           ) dl
     ) dl
GROUP BY EmpMachineID, shift_date, grouping, secondary_grouping;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=9419f91360ec8dcb5a7b1dd6a5b54184) is a db<>fiddle.